# Cordova on Android : How to stop shrinking of screen if virtual keyboard is displayed?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-softkeyboard

Helo,

I have a problem with screen shrinking on Android devices if virtual keyboard is displayed.I would like to keep screen without shrinking.

I tried to use following setting in cordova config.xml file in the root of the project:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
  <preference name="LoadingDialog" value="My Title,My Message"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

But without the luck

Or set directly these attributes:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
 android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

Into AndroidManifest.xml file. But in this case are changes each time overwritten by running cordova build command.

How can i solve it please?

Thanks for any help.

See image below:

[image]

Comment: Might be a long shot but maybe try `setFitsSystemWindows(false)` on the root view? I had the opposite problem where the view would not scroll until I added `fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: Perhaps setting a min-height on the body tag when the keyboard show even fires? `document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", function(){ //set min height on body;}, false);`  Caveats: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081949/detecting-android-softkeyboard-show-hide-events

Answer (score 0):

change manifest entry.. it will stop screen shrinking.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Comment: I cannot change manifest entry, is each time overwritten by running cordova build command. (I wrote it in question above).

Comment: You have to use a hook.  https://github.com/djett41/generator-ionic/blob/master/templates/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js looks like it might do the trick.  Create folder after_prepare in the hooks folder and copy that script.  Next add `<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustNothing" />` to your config.xml under the android platform.